# RichEdit font "tracking"

Tags: windows, fonts, richedit

I want to have extra space between each character in my RichEdit control, like so:

[image]

This feature is called "tracking" and MS Word supports it. The text from MS Word can be copied into WordPad (which uses RichEdit) and the spacing between characters is seen. However, when I copy the text into my own RichEdit control, the font is preserved, but without the desired spacing:
[image]

Note: If I copy text from my RichEdit to WordPad, the spacing **is** displayed.

What can I do to have my own RichEdit display the spacing?

I'm on Windows 7. Some MSDN docs mention "sSpacing" and "SetSpacing()" not being supported, but WordPad is working just fine.

Comment: Wordpad uses RichEdit v5, MFC uses v2.  [Check this](http://www.ucancode.net/RichEdit-Control-in-MFC-CRichEditView-MSFTEDIT.htm).

Comment: @HansPassant I'm creating the window with CreateWindowEx, and Spy++ confirms that the window's class name is RICHEDIT50W